# How to compare lists of Double using Scalatest Equality type?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
implicit val doubleEq = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(0.1)

implicit val listEq = new Equivalence[List[Double]] {
  override def areEquivalent(a: List[Double], b: List[Double]): Boolean = {
    (a, b) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => true
      case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => x === y && areEquivalent(xs, ys)
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

The first assert succeeds but the second one fails:

```
assert(1.0 === 1.01)

assert(List(1.0) === List(1.01))
```

Is there a way to have collections use the implicits I've defined for their elements as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Equality` classes are only used when importing [`TypeCheckedTripleEquals`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalautils.TypeCheckedTripleEquals):

> Provides === and !== operators that return Boolean, delegate the equality determination to an Equality type class, and require the types of the two values compared to be in a subtype/supertype relationship.

Here's the base test class I'm using to solve this:

```
import org.scalactic.{Equivalence, TolerantNumerics, TypeCheckedTripleEquals}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

abstract class UnitSpec extends FunSuite with TypeCheckedTripleEquals {
  implicit val doubleEq = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(0.001)

  implicit val listEq = new Equivalence[List[Double]] {
    override def areEquivalent(a: List[Double], b: List[Double]): Boolean = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => true
        case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => x === y && areEquivalent(xs, ys)
        case _ => false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I redefined are `areEqual` method by providing a `new Equality[List[Double]]` which is a subclass of `Equivalence[List[Double]]` considering that `areEqual` takes `Any` as the second type parameter.

```
implicit val listEq = new Equality[List[Double]] {
  def areEqual(a: List[Double], b: Any): Boolean = {
    def areEqualRec(a: List[Double], b: List[Double]): Boolean = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => true
        case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => x === y && areEquivalent(xs, ys)
        case _ => false
      }
    }
    b match {
      case daList: List[Double] => areEqualRec(a, daList)
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```